# Can someone help me with this partial derivative question?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is there a function that has partial derivatives $f_x(x, y) = x + 4y$ and
$f_y(x, y) = 3x − y$ ?

I have solved for both of the integrals so far. Getting $\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)+4xy+C=0$ and $3xy-\left(\frac{y^2}{2}\right)+C=0$ respectively. I am unsure as to where to go from there though.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I guess you are missing the important point that the constants $C$ you have are not really constants.

Comment: No.  if such a function were to exist, then $F_{xy} = F_{yx}$

Comment: @Doug, but how do you know that $f$ has second derivaives?

Answer (score 2):

By integrating $f_x$ with respect to $x$ we find that the supposed function $f$ is such that
$$f(x,y)=\int f_x(x, y)\,dx = \int (x + 4y)dx =\frac{x^2}{2}+4xy+C(y)$$
where $C(y)$ is a differentiable function which is constant with respect to $x$ (and therefore depends just on $y$).
Hence
$$f_y(x, y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+4xy+C(y)\right)=4x+C'(y)$$
which should be equal to $3x − y$.

Is there any function $C(y)$ such that $4x+C'(y)=3x-y$?

Comment: While I understand your use of the C function, why is the f_y(x,y) equal to the derivative of what you solved for rather than the original equation given? Because they are supposed to be equivalent if a function exists there?

Comment: @Isabelle $f_y(x,y)$ equal to the derivative of $f$ (obtained by integration) by definition, AND it is also equal to the original equation given.